# Check for corrupted JPEG files in Java

Tags: java, jpeg

I need a fast Java way to check if a JPEG file is valid or if it's a truncated / corrupted image.

I tried to do it in a couple of ways:

- using the javax.ImageIO library

  ```
  public boolean check(File image) throws IOException {
      try {
          BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(image);
          bi.flush();
      } catch (IIOException e) {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
  ```

  but it can detect only few corrupted files of the ones I have tested and it's very slow (on my PC around 1 image / second).
- [Apache Commons Imaging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/) library

  ```
  public boolean check(File image) throws IOException {
      JpegImageParser parser = new JpegImageParser();
      ByteSourceFile bs = new ByteSourceFile(image);
      try {
          BufferedImage bi = parser.getBufferedImage(bs, null);
          bi.flush();

          return true;
      } catch (ImageReadException e) {
          return false;
      }
  }
  ```

  This code can detect all the corrupted images I've tested, but the performances are very poor (on my PC less than 1 image / second).

I'm looking for a Java alternative to the UNIX program ***[jpeginfo](https://github.com/tjko/jpeginfo)*** which is roughly 10 times faster (on my PC around 10 images / second).

Comment: Are there particular attributes that you are using to know that the JPEG is corrupted?  I expect that a BufferedImage or JpegImageParser is looking at the entire file which would explain it being slower than what you're wanting?

Comment: With corrupted I mean that some data are missing, like a truncated file.

The set of images I need to check come from a recovery program run on a formatted hard drive (I forgot a folder in the backup...), and many of the recovered files are corrupted, with some part of the data missing, so these images are quite useless.

What I'm searching for is something that looks for problems inside the structure of the JPEG file without converting it into a raster image (that's an expensive operation).


Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I took a look at the [JPEG format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format), and to my understanding a final `EOI` (end-of-image) segment of two bytes (`FF D9`) should be last.

```java
boolean jpegEnded(String path) throws IOException {
    try (RandomAccessFile fh = new RandomAccessFile(path, "r")) {
        long length = fh.length();
        if (length < 10L) { // Or whatever
            return false;
        }
        fh.seek(length - 2);
        byte[] eoi = new byte[2];
        fh.readFully(eoi);
        return eoi[0] == -1 && eoi[1] == -39; // FF D9 (first falsely -23)
    }
}
```

Comment: should eoi[1] be a -39? singed D9's signed 8 bit is -39.

Comment: @coverboy of course, after 7 years!! Corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the best of answers, but...

The jpeginfo program you mentioned is in C. So that brings back memories of when I wanted to use code written by the Navy (That was in C++) in a Java application that I was developing.

I had two options:

1. Link my java code to the C++ (C in your case) library using JNI (Java Native Interface).
2. Translate the C++ library to java code.

Option 1 proved to be difficult to me as I need to pass an object into the library and get object(S) back from the library which forced me to do option 2 (Also, because of deadline scheduling).

So in you're case, because I don't know of any other libraries in Java that would meet your requirements, I would suggest these 2 options, or possibly build your own parser.

Comment: Seeing the rough format of a jJPEG file - a sequence of segments marked with a type code -, porting `jpeginfo` might indeed be feasible.

Comment: Second option is not so easy because jpeginfo is based on libjpeg, so a port of jpeginfo mean a port of libjpeg. First option is feasible, but I prefer to do it in a portable way

Answer (score 1):

The only way to tell for certain if a JPEG image is corrupted is to decompress it.

You ask if there is a quick way. You could certainty trade off speed for accuracy. The simplest way would be to check to see if the stream has an SOI marker at the front and an EOI marker at the end.

Next up, you could try parsing the markers to ensure they have valid values.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a native Java approach, but you can always shell out to a program like jpeginfo or [imagemagick's identify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) - the overhead of a shell may be less that the time spent by the Java libraries.

I had to do something similar, and I found that I could use Runtime.exec to call `identify -regard-warnings -verbose -` with stdin from a byte array, on a 2013 macbook pro in about 200ms (I'm checking mp3 artwork, so image sizes are around 300x300px).  Not great, but faster than 1 image per second!

(Note for my images I had to specify `-verbose` for imagemagick to pick up some errors)